# A name for set of disjoint intervals

Tags: notation, terminology

> What's in a name? That which we call a rose by any other name would smell as sweet.
>
> *William Shakespeare*

I'm looking for a short name for the phenomenon *collection of disjoint intervals*.
I currently use *selection*, which I'm not very satisfied with, and I wonder if there is a better (more conventional) name out there.

Comment: Is pairwise disjoint not good enough?

Comment: Like "pairwise disjoint collection of intervals"?

Comment: No you just need to say "pairwise disjoint intervals." No need to throw in the word "collection." It's standard terminology for a family of sets that are mutually disjoint.

Comment: But the OP is asking about a collection of intervals, not a list of them.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't see the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- More formal: Pairwise disjoint set of intervals
- Less formal: set of disjoint intervals
- Less formal: disjoint set of intervals
- Write it as something like "Let $a,b,c$ be disjoint intervals."

Basically, there is no special terminology for what you want. To avoid confusion, just don't use one. If you're using the concept a lot in a paper, you're free to make up a word, or to name the set of all such sets.

Comment: @amWhy Such complications. I think "set of pairwise disjoint intervals" is better use of language, but pairwise-disjointness is a property of the set, not of its elements.

Comment: Okay, if you say so! ;-)

Comment: In real life, it doesn't matter :P

Comment: @dfeuer You mean, real life and math are pairwise disjoint?